# How to remove elements from an std::set while iterating over it

Tags: c++, stl, coding-style, set

How can I remove elements from an `std::set` while iterating over it

My first attempt looks like:

```
set<T> s;

for(set<T>::iterator iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end(); ++iter) {
    //Do some stuff
    if(/*some condition*/)
        s.erase(iter--);
}
```

But this is problematic if we want to remove the first element from the set because `iter--` invalidates the iterator.

What's the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Standard way is to do something like

```
for(set<T>::iterator iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end();)
{
   if(/*some condition*/)
   {
      s.erase(iter++);
   }
   else
   {
      ++iter;
   }
}
```

By the first condition we are sure, that `iter` will not be invalidated anyway, since a copy of `iter` will be passed into erase, but our `iter` is already incremented, before erase is called.

In C++11, the code will be like

```
for(set<T>::iterator iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end();)
{
   if(/*some condition*/)
   {
      iter = s.erase(iter);
   }
   else
   {
      ++iter;
   }
}
```

Comment: The first peice of code fails an assertion saying that the iterators are incompatible in visual studion. Anyway, std::erase returns the new iterator, as you pointed out in your code.

Comment: The second code works for me.