# Removing an element from a std::set while iterating over it in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, erase, stdset

I've read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627458/how-to-remove-elements-from-an-stdset-while-iterating-over-it), and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874441/deleting-elements-from-stl-set-while-iterating) regarding
the erasure of elements from a `std::set` during iteration.
However, it seems that a simpler solution exists in C++17:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    std::set<int> s;

    s.insert(4);
    s.insert(300);
    s.insert(25);
    s.insert(-8);

    for (auto it:s)
    {
        if (it == -8)
        {
            s.erase(it);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "s = {";
    for (auto it:s)
    {
        std::cout << it << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it everything goes perfect:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
$ ./main
s = {4 25 300 }
```

Are there any caveats in erasing elements like that? thanks.

Comment: You're erasing by key, so you could just as well invoke `s.erase(-8)` and be done with it. The first for-loop is pointless.

Comment: I think it is valid as of C++11.

Comment: @WhozCraig this is just a POC example ... the if (it ==-8) part is just an example to pick some arbitrary element for deletion.

Comment: Ok, so is your *real* question whether using container modification during ranged-for enumeration on a `std::set`  valid in C++17 ? That problem was solved in C++11 using iterators once `std::set::erase` actually started returning one, but you want to know if it is also supported with ranged-for ? I don't think it is.

Comment: The big caveat with C++ is that "everything goes perfect" does not imply that there is no undefined behaviour. (As  Dijkstra said, testing can only show the presence of bugs, not their absence.)

Comment: To make the code valid, add `break;` after `s.erase(it);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to C++17 standard:

> 9.5.4 The range-based for statement [stmt.ranged]
>
> 1 The range-based for statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
>     auto __begin = begin-expr ;
>     auto __end = end-expr ;
>     for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin )
>     {
>         for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>         statement
>     }
> }
> ```

So **no**, your code is not valid, as you erase the element the iterator is currently pointing to (`std::set` can have only one value for the same key!), thus the iterator gets invalidated and is incremented *afterwards*, which is undefined behaviour.

Be aware that you could erase *another* element from set, as in `std::set` (as well as in `std::map` or `std::list`) only the iterator erased is invalidated whereas all others remain valid.

If you intend to remove the current element of a container (including `std::vector`, as `erase` returns a new, valid iterator), you need to fall back to a classic loop, as shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627506/1312382) to referenced question; I personally like a one-liner variant of:

```
    iter = /*some condition*/ ? container.erase(iter) : std::next(iter);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ implementation supports the Library Fundamentals TS (second edition) you can do:

```
#include <experimental/set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/iterator>
int main()
{
    std::set<int> s;

    s.insert(4);
    s.insert(300);
    s.insert(25);
    s.insert(-8);

    std::experimental::erase_if(s,
                                [](auto& key){ return key == -8; });
    std::cout << "s = {";
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(),
              std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "}\n";
}
```